# How can I convert specific sheets in an xlsx file to csv via the linux command line?

Tags: bash, csv, libreoffice

I have about 16,000 .xlsx files in a directory.  Each file follows the same structure.  The first sheet is empty, and called "Sheet 1".  The second is where the interesting data is, and it's called "Partners".  I need to convert these to text/csv.

I've tried various solutions I found online, including ssconvert, xlsx2csv, both of which produce runtime errors.  I've also tried these with a dummy file I created with Libre Office Calc, just to check it's not that my files are corrupt (and those files open fine).

How do I do this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1042624/283843

Comment: As I say in the post, xlsx2csv produces runtime errors.

Comment: The Perl programming language (`man perl`) has several libraries to read/write Excel files. See https://perlmaven.com/read-an-excel-file-in-perl

Comment: Would `ooconvert` (part of Open Office) help? Read `man ooconvert`.

Answer (score 3):

LibreOffice has a feature built in to convert to csv:

```
localc --headless --convert-to csv input.xlsx
```

This will only export the first sheet however. To get the second sheet you need the help of a macro. Open LibreOffice Calc and go to `Tools -> Macros -> Edit Macros`.

This should open an editor, replace anything in the editor with this code:

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub Main
    sheets = ThisComponent.Sheets
    sheets.removeByName("Sheet1")
    ThisComponent.storeSelf(Array())
    ThisComponent.close(true)
End Sub
```

And then save the macro (`ctrl+s`). This should save it to `Standard.Module1.Main` (says it on the bottom left).

Then you can close LibreOffice again and run the following command:

```
localc --headless input.xlsx macro:///Standard.Module1.Main
```

This will remove the first sheet (well, any sheet named `Sheet1` - change in the code if needed).

So your bash script in the end will probably look something like this:

```
mkdir csvs
for i in *.xlsx ; do
    localc --headless $i macro:///Standard.Module1.Main
    localc --convert-to csv $i
done
mv *.csv csvs/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use csvkit (https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and run

```
in2csv -I --sheet "sheetName" ./input.xlsx >./output.csv
```

It's up you to write a bash for loop.